# EMR spark-shell not picking up jars

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, emr

I am using `spark-shell` and I am unable to pick up external `jars`.  I run `spark` in EMR.

I run the following command:

```
spark-shell --jars s3://play/emr/release/1.0/code.jar
```

I get the following error:

> *OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
>   Warning: Skip remote jar s3://play/emr/release/1.0/code.jar*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This is a limitation of Apache Spark itself, not specifically Spark on EMR. When running Spark in client deploy mode (all interactive shells like `spark-shell` or `pyspark`, or `spark-submit` without `--deploy-mode cluster` or `--master yarn-cluster`), only local jar paths are allowed.

The reason for this is that in order for Spark to download this remote jar, it must already be running Java code, at which point it is too late to add the jar to its own classpath.

The workaround is to download the jar locally (using the AWS S3 CLI) then specify the local path when running spark-shell or spark-submit.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a spark-shell command line on the EMR box itself:

> spark-submit --verbose --deploy-mode cluster --class com.your.package.and.Class s3://bucket/path/to/thejar.jar 10

You can also call this command using the AWS Java EMR Client Library or the AWS CLI.  The key is to use: '--deploy-mode cluster'

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me. I'm on EMR-5.6.0/Spark-2.1.1. On what version of EMR/Spark did this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, you can add "--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster" args and it will allows you to execute s3 jars remotely

Comment: I didn't seem to need the `--master yarn` part